When should the empirical measure of an infinite sequence be defined?
Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a (deterministic) sequence of nonnegative reals, possibly even with $x_n \in \mathbb{N}$ if you prefer. Then we'd like to define the empirical measure of such a sequence as the probability measure
$$\mu := \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i}$$
whenever this limit exists. But what exactly does it mean for this limit to exist? For starters, pointwise convergence on every measurable set doesn't work, because then $\mu$ may fail to be $\sigma$-additive. Here are some of the possible definitions that we know of so far:

The limit is defined as weak convergence of measures. This is too weak for our purposes, since it doesn't even imply pointwise convergence of the CDFs.
The limit exists if the sequence of CDFs converges uniformly. This is mostly satisfactory for our purposes, but not completely. For example, it implies that the desirable equation
$$\tag{1}\int f(x) \, \mu(dx) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)$$
holds for every function $f : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ which has left and right limits at every point of $\mathbb{R}_+ \cup \{\infty\}$. However, this equation can still fail for unbounded $f$: there are sequences $(x_n)$ of natural numbers for which the sequence of CDFs converges uniformly, but (1) still fails for the identity function $f(x) = x$. This is undesirable because we want the expectation value of the empirical measure to be the limit of the sample means.
Therefore we obtain an even stronger notion of limit if we require (1) to hold for the identity function as well. But adding this single additional condition feels a bit artificial.
One also needs to be careful not to make the definition too strong. For example (1) cannot hold for (say) nonnegative measurable functions in general if the $x_n$ can be arbitrary nonnegative reals. This is because we want that if the $(x_n)$ are iid random, then $\mu$ should be the underlying distribution, and this is incompatible with (1) for $f$ being the indicator function of the sequence.

So the question is:

Is there literature on this problem? More specifically, is there literature which compares various definitions of when the empirical measure of an arbitrary sequence of natural numbers or nonnegative reals exists? And, for which classes of functions can one expect (1) to hold?

We would like to have a well-behaved definition for which both uniform convergence of the CDF holds and the expectation is the limit of the sample means.

Would this not fall (to some extent) within the scope of Sinai-Ruelle-Bowen (SRB) measures?

@AugustoSantos, thank you for the pointer! That indeed looks somewhat similar, and it's interesting that one postulates (1) for all continuous functions in that context. Some browsing of the literature hasn't turned up anything technically relevant yet, since the problems that come up in the context of SRB measures are concerned with other aspects like the dynamics and the variation of the initial condition. But it would be great have more precise pointers if you know of any.

Indeed, your framework seems more general (in particular, you are not demanding any coupling between $f$ and $\mu$).

Convergence in the Wasserstein distance is equivalent to weak convergence and convergence of moments (the number of moments depending on the exponent in the definition).

@GillesMordant I'm aware of those kinds of things, but we don't want to assume the existence of any moments (for the limiting distribution $\mu$).
